# ggplot using facet_wrap of multiple data.frame with different length in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, tidyverse, facet-wrap

I am trying to achieve the attached hand drawn figure using the code below but its showing white spaces for all the years that i do not have data for. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

D1 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-07-14"), to= as.Date("2001-07-21"), by="day"),
           A = runif(8, 0,10),
           D = runif(8,5,15)) %>% 
    gather(-Date, key = "Variable", value = "Value")

D2 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("1998-07-14"), to= as.Date("1998-08-30"), by="day"),
                 A = runif(48, 0,10),
                 D = runif(48,5,15)) %>% 
    gather(-Date, key = "Variable", value = "Value")

D <- bind_rows(D1,D2) %>% mutate(Year = year(Date))

my_linetype <- setNames(c("dashed", "solid"), unique(D$Year))

ggplot(data = D, aes(x = Date, y = Value, color = as.factor(Year), linetype = as.factor(Year)))+
  geom_line(size = 1.1)+ facet_wrap(~Variable,  scales = "free_y", nrow=2)
```

**Desired Out**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a dummy `Date` variable in your data.frame where the year is equal among different groups. In the example below this added in the `mutate()` statement under the `Unyear` variable.

```
D <- bind_rows(D1,D2) %>% mutate(Year = year(Date),
                                 Unyear = {year(Date) <- 0; Date})

my_linetype <- setNames(c("dashed", "solid"), unique(D$Year))

ggplot(data = D, aes(x = Unyear, y = Value, color = as.factor(Year), linetype = as.factor(Year)))+
  geom_line(size = 1.1)+ facet_wrap(~Variable,  scales = "free_y", nrow=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @teunbrand, I tried to use `scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("0000-07-11","0000-08-30")), expand = c(0, 0), date_breaks = "1 week")` but this gives me axis starting with `0000`. Any way to further `break` the `x-axis` in stead having only 4 default `breaks`?

Comment: Yeah that seems to be expected. You can use `date_labels = "%d-%m"` in that function to omit the year from the labels.